# mysql utf-8 support

Tags: mysql, collation

when I create a new table, it always is 'latin-swedish-ci' by default. my goal is that this table can store utf-8 text. I tried this way, give me error .

```
cd C:\mysql-5.5.14-winx64\bin
mysqld --standalone --console --default-storage-engine=InnoDB --default-character-set=utf8
 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Database probably has the default charset on latin1 and default collation set to latin1-swedish-ci and so altering the table should help

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-database.html

```
ALTER DATABASE `MyDatabaseName` 
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` worked from my sql where i needed to search through Greek letters. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always specify column encodings/collations within `CREATE TABLE` statement. This has additional benefit of making your data structure more portable in case you ever need to move it to another server.